# Reading uploaded zip file

Tags: python, google-app-engine, zip, cgi

How can i read the fileitems in zip file that uploaded using form in html and using Cgi, i tried as this:

```
form = cgi.FieldStorage() 
file_upload = form['file']
if zipfile.is_zipfile(file_upload.filename):
    print "%s is a valid pkzip file" % file_upload.filename
else:
    print "%s is not a valid pkzip file" % file_upload.filename
zfile=zipfile.ZipFile(file_upload.filename,"r")
files_zip=zfile.namelist()
```

For example when i upload (test.zip)the error is No such file or directory: 'test.zip',and if i run the code without this `zfile=zipfile.ZipFile(file_upload.filename,"r")`, i get that test.zip is not a valid pkzip file.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you passing the filename instead of the file?

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams:when i pass file i got this error:coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, cStringIO.StringO found,i ran my code in google app engine.

Comment: Ah, the version it's using probably doesn't take a file-like yet.

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams:So what i can do to read(extract )zip contents??

Comment: I'd just skip the checking and pass the file directly to `ZipFile`.

Comment: @ Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams:But this will give the previous error and i can't extract the zip file!!

Comment: No, `ZipFile` has been able to take a file-like for [a very long time now](http://docs.python.org/release/2.2/lib/zipfile-objects.html).

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams:when i wrote as :zfile=zipfile.ZipFile(file_upload.file,"r")//i get the error that ::coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, cStringIO.StringO found,so i can't read the zip file to  extract it's contents.

Comment: Then GAE is using a broken version of `zipfile`. Dunno what to tell you.

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams:Sorry but i didn't understand the last comment!!

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams:class ZipFile(file)
Open a ZIP file, where file can be either a path to a file (a string) or a file-like object,how can i get the path of the uploaded file to put it as argument in ZipFile??

Comment: You shouldn't need to, since you have a file-like.

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams:But it gave error,sorry but i really want a solution for this problem as soon as possible.

Comment: @ Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams:Thank you very much,it worked correctly now.Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try to pass `file_upload.file` to `ZipFile` instead of `file_upload.filename`.

Here's a script that prints the list of files in the zip file:

```
import sys
sys.stderr = sys.stdout
print "Content-Type: text/plain"
print

import cgi
import zipfile

form = cgi.FieldStorage()

filefield = form['somefile']
print "Filename:", filefield.filename

if filefield.file is not None and zipfile.is_zipfile(filefield.file):
    zfile = zipfile.ZipFile(filefield.file)
    print "Name list:\n\t",
    print "\n\t".join(zfile.namelist())
```

And the corresponding html form:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="file-upload" method=post>
<p><label for=somefile>File: <input type=file name=somefile>
<p><input type=submit>
</form>
```